# Logrotation in web server

Tags: linux, apache, webserver, logrotate

I have set up logrotation in one of my webserver, but it is not working for my custom requirement in /etc/logrotate.d/customfile. Below are the logrotate.conf, logrotate.d/customfile and and cron.daily from /etc directory. How do I make it work for configuration details in customfile?

/etc/logrotate.conf

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
compress

# RPM packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp and btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
        minsize 1M
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0600 root utmp
    rotate 1
}
```

/etc/logrotate.d/customfile

```
"/app/logs/website.com/error_log" "/app/logs/website.com/access_log" {
   daily
   size 500M
   missingok
   rotate 30
   compress
   delaycompress
   nomail
   create 644 admin admin
   sharedscripts
   postrotate
      if [ -f /app/instance/sites/website.com/run/httpd.pid ]; then
         su - admin -c /app/instance/sites/website.com/gracefulApache.sh > /dev/null
      fi
   endscript
   }
```

/etc/cron.daily/logrotate

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/sbin/logrotate -s /var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status /etc/logrotate.conf
EXITVALUE=$?
if [ $EXITVALUE != 0 ]; then
    /usr/bin/logger -t logrotate "ALERT exited abnormally with [$EXITVALUE]"
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: Can you describe "it is not working" in greater detail? In this form, what is it doing? What is it not doing?

Comment: It is not rotating the logs on daily basis or even when the size reaches 500mb.

Comment: OK, have you attempted to debug the current configuration at all? `logrotate` has a `-d` flag that performs a dry-run to test configurations.

Comment: Yeah. No issues there. That works fine. Anything to do with /etc/cron.daily/logrotate so that it can run on its own?

Comment: That file should be executable for sure. You can verify that the logrotate job is in fact being run by looking at the file cron logs into, /var/log/cron on RH flavors, I don't know your distro. You should see lines like `Sep  1 03:18:01 hostname run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[19886]: starting logrotate` and `Sep  1 03:18:01 hostname run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[19894]: finished logrotate` if logrotate is executing properly through cron.

Comment: Looks like that is also working fine. 
`Sep  2 03:01:01 hostname anacron[10905]: Will run job 'cron.daily' in 47 min.`
`Sep  2 03:48:01 hostname anacron[10905]: Job 'cron.daily' started`
`Sep  2 03:48:01 hostname run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[15222]: starting logrotate`
`Sep  2 03:48:01 hostname run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[15237]: finished logrotate`
`Sep  2 03:48:01 hostname anacron[10905]: Job 'cron.daily' terminated`
`Sep  3 03:01:01 hostname anacron[18091]: Will run job 'cron.daily' in 48 min.`

Comment: So I tried to run debug in another host and below is what I could see. Steps - Logged in with user, then sudo to root. Ran - `logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.d/customfile`. Output was - `[root@hostname website.com]# logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.d/customfile
Ignoring /etc/logrotate.d/customfile because the file owner is wrong (should be root).`

Comment: Now, I have changed the owner to root from user. Ran debug again, and this time I am getting

`rotating pattern: "/app/logs/website.com/error_log" "/app/logs/website.com/access_log" 524288000 bytes (30 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /app/logs/website.com/error_log
error: skipping "/app/logs/website.com/error_log" because parent directory has insecure permissions (It's world writable or writable by group which is not "root") Set "su" directive in config file to tell logrotate which user/group should be used for rotation.`

Comment: Mattias wrote a nice explanation about what you're encountering here: https://ma.ttias.be/logrotate-on-rhelcentos-7-complains-about-insecure-permissions-on-parent-directory-world-writable. I don't think it's indicative of what is wrong on the original machine or you'd be seeing it there as well obviously.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Since I had root permissions I have changed the user of that customfile to root. Not getting that error anymore. But now, when I do a forceful logrotate - `logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/customfile` I could see it rotate the logs without compressing `-rw-r--r--. 1 admin admin 1.2G Sep  4 05:50 access_log.1`
`-rw-r--r--. 1 admin admin  93G Sep  4 05:50 error_log.1`
`-rw-r--r--. 1 admin admin 1.5K Sep  4 05:50 error_log`
`-rw-r--r--. 1 admin admin 1.5K Sep  4 05:51 access_log`

Comment: My concern here is, why is it not doing this automatically on daily purpose or after reaching 500mb? Also I get this at the end of output - `error: error creating output file /var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status.tmp: Permission denied`

Comment: 1) Your config specifies delaycompress which delays compression until the next rotation cycle; 2) Logrotate won't do anything automatically when a file hits a certain size, so don't expect it to. Logrotate only considers rotations when it's run; 3) Do you have SELinux enabled? Do you see an audit denial for logrotate in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`?

Comment: 3) Do you have SELinux enabled? Yes `SELinux status:enabled` `Current mode: permissive` . Do you see an audit denial for logrotate - No `# grep logrotate /var/log/audit/audit.log
#`

Comment: yeah idk man, out of ideas at the moment

Comment: Not a problem @parttimeturtle. I will update once resolved. Thanks for the suggestions!